# How to stop live time in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I want to stop live time in java script. How can I do it. This is my live time java script source code.

```
        setInterval(function(){
        var d = new Date()
        var h = d.getHours()
        var m = d.getMinutes()
        var s = d.getSeconds()
        h = (h < 10) ? ("0" + h) : h;
        m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m;
        s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s;
        document.getElementById("time").value = h +":"+m+":"+s
}, 1000)


document.getElementById("time").setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
document.getElementById("time").clearInterval(value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `clearInterval` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

> The clearInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin cancels a timed, repeating action which was previously established by a call to setInterval().

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
        var d = new Date()
        var h = d.getHours()
        var m = d.getMinutes()
        var s = d.getSeconds()
        h = (h < 10) ? ("0" + h) : h;
        m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m;
        s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s;
        document.getElementById("time").value = h +":"+m+":"+s
}, 1000)

// this will cancel the interval when you want it to
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: if this field mandatory how we can click submit button. its getting error